# Django - Parsing URL in any order?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework

I am setting up a Django/Django Rest Framework API and most of the queries are generated using parameters inside the url. The pattern follows `{param name}/{param value}`.

For example:

```
users/
users/id/{id}/
users/name/{name}/
users/group/{group}/name/{name}/
users/group/{group}/email/{email}/
```

The parameters are parsed with regexes and sent to view methods as in the tutorial. Each of these three has a separate view method.

I am curious if there is a way to write one view method that can capture all of these parameters, no matter the order they are presented in. For example:

```
users/id/{id}/
users/group/{group}/
users/name/{name}/
users/email/{email}/
users/email/{email}/group/{group}
```

Would all go to one view method that filters the User model/table. Is it possible to write a concise regex/url resolver that does this without having to write a url pattern match that covers all possible iterations?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use query string instead.

query: /users/?email=user@example.com&name=Doge

Then in your views:

```
email = self.request.query_params.get('email', None)
name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
```

Your url pattern would just look like:

```
r'^/users/$'
```

Or you could do:

```
r'^/users/{paramtype}/{param}/({subparamtype}/{subparam})?$'
```

But then you have to check for all cases in your view:

```
if paramtype == 'id': # query on id in param
elif paramtype == 'email' # query on email in param
elif ...
```

Comment: I had considered this as a backup but I am also curious to see if it is doable stricly within the url.